# Mapreduce way to convert all elements of String[] to int[] in Java?

Tags: java, lambda, mapreduce, string-conversion

You can convert all elements of a `String` array to `int`s and store them in an `int` array like this:

```
public static final void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "1 2 5 17 23 12 5 72 123 74 13 19 32";
    String[] strAr = input.split(" ");

    int[] output = parseIntArray(strAr);
}

private static int[] parseIntArray(String[] strAr) {
    // convert to int[] one by one
    int[] output = new int[strAr.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < strAr.length; i++) {
        output[i] = Integer.parseInt(strAr[i]);
    }

    return output;
}
```

How can you write the `parseIntArray(String[])` method in a map-reduce fashion in Java?

I heard that there is a simple way to do this with lambdas in Java 8. Was there also a map-reduce fashion way to do this prior to Java 8? I know this is two questions in one; however I believe that they are so closely related that it is better for the community to have both of these answers on one page.

Answer (score 6):

One way to write it would be:

```
private static int[] parseIntArray(String[] strAr) {
  return Stream.of(strAr).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
}
```

You could also start directly from the string:

```
private static final Pattern splitOnSpace = Pattern.compile(" ");

private static int[] parseIntArray(String str) {
  return splitOnSpace.splitAsStream(str).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
}
```

Comment: Any idea which one would be the most efficient ? I think they would be the same in term of performance, but maybe one is a little better then the other ? Upvoted.

Comment: I suspect the latter would be better because the pattern is pre-compiled but the difference is probably small.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with lambdas in Java 8

```
private static int[] parseIntArray(String input) {

    return Arrays.asList(input.split(" "))
            .stream()
            .flatMapToInt(n-> IntStream.of(Integer.parseInt(n)) )
            .toArray();
}
```

I personally prefer the for loop, I think it is more readable.

Before Java 8 you could use something like rxJava and use anonymous classes.

Comment: Although this works, it is a little inefficient to create a list and an IntStream.

Comment: Yes, seeing your answer is great. I have not had much use for steams and need some practice

Answer (score 0):

Another simple proposition :

```
String input = "1 2 5 17 23 12 5 72 123 74 13 19 32";
int[] numbers = Stream.of(input.split(" ")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
```